# Devise is not sending user to root after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The default behavior of Devise should be to send the user to the root path after login. Mine is failing to do that and instead is simply rendering the login page again. It is logging the user in. It is just not redirecting properly.

#### development.log (with comments showing user actions)

```
# Starting from root

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-06 23:11:21 +0800
Processing by JobsController#index as HTML
  Rendering jobs/index.html.haml within layouts/application
  [1m[36mJob Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" ORDER BY created_at DESC[0m
  Rendered jobs/index.html.haml within layouts/application (23.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 366ms (Views: 352.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

# Click 'Sign In' link

Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-06 23:11:22 +0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (36.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 84.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

# Fill in username and password and submit

Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-06 23:11:47 +0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ahemte4a2+/IEs3Fgiz9GRiu5GesxdWv5ZDK1sC0gqm0yerpppH+xGfktJvUyQOcgsjoEZlPqt/dy+I5tkLJjw==", "user"=>{"login"=>"josh", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (lower(username) = 'josh' OR lower(email) = 'josh') ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "users" SET "remember_created_at" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3[0m  [["remember_created_at", "2018-02-06 15:11:47.637205"], ["updated_at", "2018-02-06 15:11:47.637995"], ["id", 1]]
  [1m[35m (20.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3[0m  [["username", "josh"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3[0m  [["email", "joshuaikesling@gmail.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "josh"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (8.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 265ms (Views: 54.6ms | ActiveRecord: 25.6ms)

# Landing back on sign in page (expected result was redirect to root path)
```

#### sessions/new.html.haml

```
.row
  .col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3
    %h2 Log in
    = simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      .form-inputs
        = f.input :login, required: false, autofocus: true
        = f.input :password, required: false
        = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, input_html: { checked: true } if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, "Log in", class: 'btn-success', class: 'btn-success'
    %h4.button-alt-link Don't have an account? #{link_to 'Sign up here!', new_user_registration_path}
```

#### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: %i[show index]

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || request.env['omniauth.origin'] || root_path
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :admin]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```

#### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cvs
  devise_for :users
  resources :agents
  resources :jobs

  root to: "jobs#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

#### initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.authentication_keys = [:login]

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email, :username]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email, :username]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11

  config.send_email_changed_notification = true

  config.send_password_change_notification = true

  config.reconfirmable = true

  config.confirmation_keys = [ :username ]

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = 6..128

  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  config.lock_strategy = :none

  config.reset_password_keys = [ :username ]

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  config.sign_out_via = :delete

end
```

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?('/')
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'aws-sdk-rails', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'country_select', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.1'
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.5'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.2.1"
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :cv

  has_many :educations, through: :cvs, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :languages, through: :cvs, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :jobs

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { in: 4..50 }
  validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, multiline: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_format_of :email, with: /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/, multiline: true
  validate :validate_username

  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(['lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value', { value: login.downcase }]).first
    else
      if conditions[:username].nil?
        where(conditions).first
      else
        where(username: conditions[:username]).first
      end
    end
  end

  def validate_username
    errors.add(:username, :invalid) if User.where(email: username).exists?
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe wrong email or password? This is the normal behaviour  in this case.

Comment: It is successfully signing the user in. I've double checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting validation errors, based on this rollback in the logs:

```
  ...
  1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3[0m  [["username", "josh"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3[0m  [["email", "joshuaikesling@gmail.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "josh"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m

  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  ...
```

possibly caused by some validation on your user model?

Make sure you are rendering both of these flash message keys in your application layout as that is what devise will write to:

`flash[:notice]` and `flash[:alert]`

---

Side note:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :admin]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
end
```

The above code seems sketchy to me, maybe a non-issue? `:admin` probably should not be whitelisted for `:sign_up`, maybe I am wrong? Maybe not for `account_update` either without verifying the user is an admin - but I don't have any context so maybe I am off base.

The initializer for Devise already has a REGEX for validating email format. Removing the validation from the User model fixes the issue. The validation in the model was feeding Devise a silent error causing it to re-render the login page even though it was successfully signing the user in, instead of redirecting the user to the root path after sign in.

Comment: The validation would only effect the creation of a new user, correct? The errors are rendered for all pages in `application.html.haml` and work properly. If I try to sign in with an incorrect password, for instance. I'm not getting an error, I'm simply not being redirected to the root path. I can create a new account and sign in with no issues. The user is being successfully signed in. As far as the admin permitted attribute, I need that to allow an existing admin to assign admin privileges to a typical user account. Without whitelisting, an admin can't promote another user.

Comment: `added_attrs << :admin if current_user.admin?` is probably a lot safer

Comment: I see. Thank you. Is there a way I can see exactly what is causing the rollback? I don't think it's causing the redirect failure, but, you never know.

Comment: It is doing an `User Exists` query (3 times?) my guess is that is from a unique validation on email and username - devise is adding some of those by default perhaps and then maybe you have an additional one (duplicate)? look at the 3 queries between `BEGIN` and `ROLLBACK` one of those possibly an issue caused by a validation? I am just making a guess here... maybe it is something else

Comment: That is peculiar. Devise, by default, only allows log in with email address. I followed the instructions in their docs to allow both email and username to be login keys. According to the docs, it does check to make sure someone doesn't try to create a username that is the same as an existing email address. It seems to be running those validations when logging a user in. Although I do need to explore that, that is for another question. lol. I'm not sure that would cause the redirect to fail, but, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I think devise doesn't redirect because the validation looks like an error to it, notice the first two queries use `LOWER` because of this config `config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email, :username]` but last query does not use `LOWER` making me think it is a duplicate validation, can you post your User model code?

Comment: Ok. I added the user.rb file.

Comment: Yeah, the last call is the bottom validation where it checks to see if the username matches an email address already in the db. I still don't understand why it would run these validations on an attempted login? Shouldn't they only be run on a new record being saved? Or does it run them all every time because it has to add timestamps and session info and whatnot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164642/discussion-between-josh-and-house9).

Comment: try commenting out all of those validations; pretty sure that `validate_username` is the issue, you only want that on `create` not during an `update`? or if username can change the logic is not 100% correct, because it matches itself and errors out.  I think validations are firing because devise updates some of the attributes when the user logs in - got to go to a meeting I'll check back later...

Comment: Commenting out the validations does it. So you are right about that. I went through and commented them out 1 by 1. Removing any 1 validation still results in a failure to redirect, except the line `validates_format_of :email, with: /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/, multiline: true`. Commenting out that line alone results in a successful login with proper redirect.

Comment: Ok. The Devise initializer already has an email validation. I changed the validation regex it uses to match the one in my model and removed the model validation. Everything now seems to be working as expected. It is allowing login and redirecting properly and it is throwing the expected errors if I try to create a new account using a nonvalid format email address. Thank you so much for your help. I am going to edit the answer to include this info and then mark it as answered.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to `ApplicationController.rb`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end
```

Comment: I think this is the default devise implementation?